# Proving the NP hardness of two variants of SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, satisfiability

$k$-$\text{RSAT}$ is a variant of $k$-$\text{SAT}$ where we restrict our attention to formulae in
which each variable occurs at most $3$ times, and each literal occurs at most twice. The language
$k$-$\text{RSAT}$ is $$\{\phi \in k{-}\text{SAT} \mid \text{ no variable (literal) occurs  more than 3 (2) times in }\phi \}.$$

$k$-$\text{NAESAT}$ is a variant of $k$-$\text{SAT}$ where we allow only assignments in which at
least one literal in each clause evaluates to $0$.

I'm trying to prove that $k$-$\text{RSAT}$ and $3$-$\text{NAESAT}$ are $\text{NP}$ hard. If it helps, the previous subpart to this problem involved proving that $k$-$\text{NSAT}$ (defined below) is $NP$ hard (which I've proven).

$k$-$\text{NSAT}$ is a variant of $k$-$\text{SAT}$ where, given a $k{-}\text{CNF}$ formula $\phi$ and a natural number $n$, the problem is to determine if there exists an assignment for which at least $n$ clauses of $\phi$ evaluate to 1

How do I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a gadget that lets you copy variables. Given a variable $x$, there is a gadget that allows you to create a copy of $x$, that is, a new variable $x'$ such that any satisfying assignment of the gadget satisfies $x = x'$. Using your gadget, you create enough copies of each variable, and then replace each occurrence of a variable by a single copy of the variable.

Comment: I added a small edit to my question, I'm trying to prove that $3-NAESAT$ is $NP$ hard (Not $k-NAESAT$, I have a proof for $4-NAESAT$). Your idea seems to work for $k-RSAT$ but I can't think of how to apply it to $3-NAESAT$?

Comment: I bet that it works also for 3NAESAT.